# Cannot compile Qt project due to dll problems

Tags: qt, dll, mingw

I am trying to create a Qt program that is able to control an Amptek 8000a MCA (a device that is connected via COM port for radiation detection purposes). The manufacturer provides c++, labview and vb [API](http://www.amptek.com/mca8000a-multichannel-analyzer-software-downloads/), but I am having a lot of trouble with Qt (C++) to recognise the dll. I have added the library using Qt's in-built add library function but I get lots of errors `undefined reference to...` e.g. error: `undefined reference to PmcaPowerUp@4`. The relevent part of my pro file looks like:

```
win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/Libraries/ -lPMCADLL

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/Libraries
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/Libraries

win32:!win32-g++: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/Libraries/PMCADLL.lib
```

Can I use the .dll provided in the package above? 
Do I have to compile it myself with mingw/qt? 
It's giving me a lot of trouble when all you have to do with Matlab is `loadlibrary('PMCADLL.dll','PmcaCom.h')`. 
Done.

How I can get my project to link to the dll correctly or use `mingw` to compile the dll with the source files the manufacturer provides?

Comment: What is your mentioned "Qt in-build add library function"? If you load it via C++ code remove it from the pro file and vice versa. Not sure why you add it to PRE_TARGETDEPS. If i understand this correctly, you obtain an DLL and header for use in your project. First would be to find out if this DLL is compatible to your compiler ( http://mingw.org/wiki/msvc_and_mingw_dlls - MSVC and MinGW). The code looks good so far, it may just not be compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a dll you have was generate on a platform or even with a compiler that is not compatable with your own you may (and would) have problems with it. So if you have a source code the best way is to compile a dll using it. Take a look at [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/sharedlibrary.html).

Comment: Thanks Mikhail. I figured that out today by switching to the MSCV version of Qt - the documentation for the libraries I was using said "Visual C++" but I interpreted that as "C++ with GUI". So all solved and working now :) Before I did that I actually compiled it with mingw (the source code was provided), but it didn't actually do anything with the hardware, but at least it compiled.